# Execute code when item pressed in NavDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

I am using a Navigation Drawer with a NavController, which means I define the navigation to other fragments in my nav_graph file. The navigation drawer has 3 items (To-do, profile and logout), the first two items (To-Do and profile) change the current fragment (and this works fine) but the third item (logout) should execute some code by calling a function, but with navController I can only change fragments, if I implement the OnNavigationOnItemSelectedListner, it disables the navController functionality (fragments won't change unless I write the code to do so in the listener). Is there a way to implement the code for logout item without disabling the NavController?

This is part of the code I am Using

Activity

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_todo, R.id.nav_profile), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_todo">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_todo"
        android:name="com.lepe.helloandroidkotlin.ToDoFragment"
        android:label="To - Do"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_to_do"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.lepe.helloandroidkotlin.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="Profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile"/>

</navigation>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding a listener just to the Log Out item of the Navigation Drawer. To do so, I get an instance of the Nav Drawer Menu then I find the Item I want to listen to and add the listener.

In this case, just to test, I finish the activity.

```
val menu: Menu = navView.getMenu()
        val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout)
        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            this.finish()
            true
        }
```